# Arabic text stripper / parser

Tags: swift

I'm new to programming. I made a function that removes the vowels on Arabic text input. My question is if I used the best loop for the task or is there a better and more concise way to write this?

It would be nice to improve the code. Thank you.

```
// It seems to work now. I solved it.
// What do you think? :) Happy that I managed to solve it.
// Programming is fun!!! :D
var arabic:String = "الْعَرَبِيَّةُ لُغَةٌ جَمِيلَةٌ"

func txtStripper(arabic: String) -> String {
    var strippedTxt = ""
    for character in arabic {
        if character != "َ" && character != "ِ" && character != "ّ" && character != "ْ" && character != "ُ" && character != "ٌ" && character != "ً" && character != "ٍ" {
            strippedTxt += toString(print(character))
        }
    }
    return strippedTxt
}
txtStripper(arabic)
```

Comment: A funny fact. I sat several hours and solved the code. Do you know what the problem was? I forgot to convert print(character) to String. :) At least I'm making an effort to solve things myself too. =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you can clean up the `if` statement by using `contains` function.

```
func txtStripper(arabic: String) -> String {
    var strippedTxt = ""
    let vowels : Character[] = ["َ", "ِ", "ّ", "ْ", "ُ", "ٌ", "ً", "ٍ"]

    for character in arabic {
        if !contains (vowels, character) {
            strippedTxt += toString(character)
        }
    }
    return strippedTxt
}
```

Next, if you are comfortable with closures, you can rewrite the whole function in much more concise way as follows:

```
func txtStripperWithClosures(arabic:String) -> String {
    let vowels : Character[] = ["َ", "ِ", "ّ", "ْ", "ُ", "ٌ", "ً", "ٍ"]
    return Array(arabic).filter({!contains(vowels, $0)}).reduce("",+)
}
```

It works as follows:

- `Array(arabic)` turns the String into Character[]
- `filter({!contains(vowels, $0)})` removes the vowel characters from the array
- `reduce("",+)` joins the character list back into a String

Comment: Thank you for the awesome feedback. I'll read more about closures. Looks very neat.